# Legend by colors rather than by colors*groups in an R plotly violin plot

Tags: r, plotly, legend, violin-plot

I have count data from two groups (`G1` and `G2`), where the first group has counts from two types (`T1` and `T2`) and the second group has counts from three types (`T1`, `T2`, and `T3`):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(count = rpois(100,100),
                 type = c(rep("T1",20), rep("T2",20), rep("T1",20), rep("T2",20), rep("T3",20)),
                 group = c(rep("G1",40), rep("G2",60)),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to draw these data in a violin plot using `R`'s `plotly`, where the colors are by `type` and the x-axis location is by `group`. Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
df$type <- factor(df$type)

library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = df$group, y = df$count, split = df$group, type = 'violin', box = list(visible = F), points = F,showlegend = T, color = df$type)
```

Which gives:
[image]

As you can see the legend shows the expansion of `type` * `group`, but I want it to only show `type` (i.e., follow the `color` argument in the `plot_ly` function).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Remove the `split` argument.